# How can I get the OTSU thresholds of 100 images in an array without using for loop?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a (100,64,64) Numpy array which stores 100 64*64 images, and now I want to get the OTSU thresholds of each image, how can I achieve that without a for loop as it is slow?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to make it at once? what is the point?

Comment: so oyu assume the overhead of the loop to produce much processing overhead? Probably that's not true.

Comment: the for loop as you describe it should be fast. Maybe the problem is how you rebuild / modify the array? things like np.insert and np.append can be slow because they copy the underlying array each time.

Comment: Since Otsu treats each pixel equally, you can reshape it into a 2d array and run Otsu on it.